# Matplotlib: creating a scatter plot where each point is colored (weighted) based on its count of instances in the dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset of N=910 probabilities, and hte probabilites are represented as all integers between 5 and 90 that are divisible by 5. This constitutes my x input. Each probability has a boolean response associated with it, the booleans being encoded using a 0 for false and a 1 for true. Some code to recreate this.

```
x_inpt = np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 91, 5), 910)
y_inpt = np.random.choice([0, 1], 910)
```

A lot of the line plots for my actual data look like this.

[image]

(and for curiosity sake, here's the original code used for this plot)

```
    plt.scatter(x_inpt, y_inpt)
    plt.ylabel("Decisions On Adminstering Experimental Treatment")
    plt.xlabel("Harm probabilities")
    plt.xticks(range(0, 101, 10))
    plt.yticks([0.0, 1.0], labels=["No", "Yes"])
    title_str = "Pilot Data From " + str(exp_count) + " Experiments / " + str(num_trials) + " trials"  
    plt.title(title_str)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Even though this image has 910 data points, they all get placed on top of one another other. There's multiple instances of the same data point, or multiple instances of the same x y coordinate being plotted in my data.

I wanted to find a way to make data points that have the most instances be darker (or lighter) just to make this graph more clearly informative.

But I'm not really sure how to, and my code is stuck looking like the code sample I posted for the above plot. I seem to be having a rough time parsing matplotlib  documentation and figuring out how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps silly solution to this would be something like hashing each point based on (x,y) so it always is unique and counting this up:

```
# hash (x_inpt,y_input)
def hash(x,y):
    # Dummy sum since we have two nice integer arrays
    return x+y

hashed_output = hash(x_inpt, y_inpt)
x_y_weights = np.bincount(hashed_output)
color_for_each_sample = x_y_weights[hashed_output]

...

plt.scatter(x_inpt, y_inpt, c=color_for_each_sample)
plt.colorbar()

...
```

I'm working on a more elegant version now

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind `pandas`, you could use something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x_inpt, 'y':y_inpt})
grp = df.groupby(['x','y']).size().reset_index()

a = plt.scatter(grp['x'], grp['y'], c=grp[0], cmap='cool')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Number of points', rotation=-90, va="bottom")
plt.ylabel("Decisions On Adminstering Experimental Treatment")
plt.xlabel("Harm probabilities")
plt.xticks(range(0, 101, 10))
plt.yticks([0.0, 1.0], labels=["No", "Yes"])
title_str = "Pilot Data"
plt.title(title_str)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a counter to count each x,y pair. And then use scatter to either change the color or the size of the dots. Or even a number in text form. The size is proportional to the area of the dot, so I squared it in the demo below.

Just to show the possibilities, the three ways are combined in the experimental code. In practise, you'd probably only use one of the methods.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

num_trials = 910
x_inpt = np.random.choice(np.arange(5, 91, 5), num_trials)
y_inpt = np.random.choice([0, 1], num_trials)

count = Counter(zip(x_inpt, y_inpt))

xs = np.array([x for (x, y), c in count.items()])
ys = np.array([y for (x, y), c in count.items()])
cs = np.array([c for (x, y), c in count.items()])
cmin = cs.min()
cmax = cs.max()
cmid = (cmin + cmax) / 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=cs, cmap='plasma', s=1200*cs*cs/(cmax * cmax))
for (x, y), c in count.items():
    # the maximum fontsize is set to 22
    # the color is either white or black the contrast with the color of the scatter dot
    ax.text(x, y, c, color='w' if c<cmid else 'k', fontsize=22*c/cmax, ha='center', va='center')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_title('Counts')
plt.ylabel("Decisions On Adminstering\nExperimental Treatment")
plt.xlabel("Harm probabilities")
plt.xticks(range(0, 91, 10))
plt.ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.yticks([0, 1], labels=["No", "Yes"])
title_str = f"Pilot Data From {20} Experiments / {num_trials} trials"
plt.title(title_str)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is another example, supposing the data has a binomial distribution and using the reversed colormap without the numbers.

```py
y_inpt = np.random.choice([0, 1], num_trials)
x_inpt = np.where(y_inpt == 0,
                  np.random.binomial(20, 0.5, num_trials),
                  np.random.binomial(20, 0.3, num_trials)) * 5
```

[image: second example]